# jQuery UI sortable triggers css3 animation on sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a few sortables with CSS3 keyframe animations defined on them through a class. When sorting, I've noticed strange behaviour as seen in [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvnzffoh/)

```
.slideLeft {
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;    

  animation-duration: 1s;   
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;   
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;       

  visibility: visible !important;   
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
     transform: translateX(150%);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateX(-8%);
  }
  65%{
    transform: translateX(4%);
  }
  80%{
    transform: translateX(-4%);
  }
  95%{
    transform: translateX(2%);
  }         
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

Initiating jQuery sortable.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

The animation triggers on sort `start` and `stop`, while the animation class is not being reapplied. It's seems like there is some sort of reflow going on caused by jQuery modifying the DOM. But how does it keep triggering the animation, and can it be avoided? The goal is to have no animation at all when sorting, while keeping the class.

***Answer:*** It makes sense, since the item we're dragging around is just a clone, it animates on `start` because we insert the clone to the DOM. The animation occurring on `stop` has the same cause, since the clone is then being append to it's new position, again triggering a reflow of the document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, you need is remove the `slideLeft` class from li items after animation finish. Something like:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    //one second later the slideLeft class  is removed from each li.
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $( "#sortable" ).find(".slideLeft").removeClass("slideLeft");
    }, 1000)
```

});

I hope to be useful.

PD.

When sorting a list, jquery-ui changes the DOM because the element is removed and inserted again. In addition jquery-ui creates another element with the same properties as placeholder, showing the place to move the element.

Then if you don't remove the `slideLeft` class, the animation will play with each change in the list

Comment: I have to keep the class, so removing it is not a solution. But your answer is really close to the answer I'm looking for, explaining _why_ the animation replays. It makes sense, since the item we're sorting around is just a clone, it animates on `start` because we insert the clone to the DOM. The animation occurring on `stop` has the same cause, since the clone is then being append to it's new position, again triggering a reflow of the document. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[image]Your forcing the placeholder li to be visible using !important.

```
    .slideLeft {
        animation-name: slideLeft;
        -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;  

        animation-duration: 1s; 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

        visibility: visible !important; 
    }
```

If you inspect in the jfiddle you'll see that the ui-sortable-placeholder has inline

```
    style="visibility:hidden;"
```

which is getting overwritten by the last line in the css above.  You can either re-overwrite it with something like:

```
    .ui-sortable-placeholder{
         visibility: hidden !important;    

     }
```

or something similar.  This will make the slide left part also invisible and just show the "bounce" portion of the animation (not sure if that is what you want or not).

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's still only working after I sort a second time. Why is this? Have a look at this forked [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuck51r0/). Note: I don't see anything bouncing, could you clarify what you're seeing? There is no animation at all in this version, which is good.

Comment: Which "Item" are you looking at?  Note that in the fiddle only "Item 1" has the .slideLeft class on it so that is the only one which will show that animation.  The others can sort but will not show the animation because they don't have the class attached.  In the fiddle you linked, "Item 1" is working correctly.  To fix it, add the class="slideLeft" to the rest of the li.

Comment: You're right I completely overlooked that. But, that means it's not solving the animation being triggered. Items with `slideLeft` should _not_ animate when sorting. Could you provide a Fiddle where this part of your answer: _This will make the slide left part also invisible and just show the "bounce" portion of the animation_ is demonstrated?

Comment: Is this what you want?   http://jsfiddle.net/xfxjp0th/2/     I just added the class to all of the li and removed the top line from the two keyframe sections.  The top line was showing 150% which is what caused the slide effect.  The smaller percentages are what handles the bounce portion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the class, but need to prevent the animation, you can do:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    beforeStop: function( event, ui ) {
       $(ui.item).css("animation", "none");
    }
});
```

And it's good to put in your css:

```
#sortable .ui-sortable-placeholder { visibility: hidden !important; animation: none; }
```

Your fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvnzffoh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could add this below your script

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#sortable" ).children("li").first().removeClass('slideLeft');
}, 1000);
```

This script waits for the animation to end (1000 ms) and then removes the class `slideLeft`from the first list-item. BUT, if you're fast and you select the first row within the second, the problem persists. So what I would do is wrap your script around the timeout-function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).children("li").first().removeClass('slideLeft');
}, 1000);
```

This waits a second (1000ms) to make the list sortable. After that second it also removes the class `slideLeft` to prevent continues animation. Downside is that you cannot sort the list for 1 second.

Here is the complete fiddle based on your script:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
  });
  $("#sortable").children("li").first().removeClass('slideLeft');
}, 1000);
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}
#sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
#sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
.slideLeft {
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(150%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-8%);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateX(4%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-4%);
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateX(2%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-8%);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default slideLeft"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Won't go with this, the class should remain since I need it to be there. I'm looking for answer explaining _why_ it keeps triggering.